# Figures with nice caption style

Tags: floats, captions

I am using the code below to layout captions of listings. How can I achieve the same effect for figures, i.e. having a colored frame and the same caption style? While I would like the background of the caption to slightly overlap the figure's frame, I do *not* want it to overlap the actual figure. Moreover, I'd like to use that style for figures with both captions on top and at the bottom.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\noindent\colorbox{blue}{\hspace{1em}#1#2#3\hspace{1em}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white,
singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt,font={bf,sf,footnotesize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Listing with nice caption style.},frame=single,rulecolor=\color{blue}]
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\resizebox{5cm}{!}{\LaTeX}
\caption{Figure with caption at bottom.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Figure with caption on top.}
\resizebox{5cm}{!}{\LaTeX}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should let you start.

I've defined

```
\captionsetup[figure]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white,aboveskip=-10pt,
singlelinecheck=false, margin=3pt,font={bf,sf,footnotesize}}
```

and encased the contents of `figure`s in a `mdframed` environment.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\noindent\colorbox{blue}{\hspace{1em}#1#2#3\hspace{1em}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white,
singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt,font={bf,sf,footnotesize}}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white,aboveskip=-10pt,
singlelinecheck=false, margin=3pt,font={bf,sf,footnotesize}}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Listing with nice caption style.},frame=single,rulecolor=\color{blue}]
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{mdframed}[innerbottommargin=10pt,linecolor=blue]
\resizebox{5cm}{!}{\LaTeX}
\end{mdframed}
\caption{Figure with caption at bottom.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Figure with caption on top.}
\begin{mdframed}[innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=blue]
\resizebox{5cm}{!}{\LaTeX}
\end{mdframed}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to make the figure's top caption overlap the frame as for the other cases?

Comment: @Florian Not with this solution. Unfortunately the caption is typeset before the figure frame...